# how to make Django search hyperlink in PDF?

Tags: python, django, pdf, hyperlink

I want to ask some questions about Django

Now I have a simple search engine built by Django

Besides, I can get the search results based on the search query

However, I want to add the hyperlink function.

I want to the search results on the result page can be clickable and link to the original publisher.

so, my question is how to make Django search the hyperlink in the PDF and display on the new web page?

Comment: which PDF? You can scrap the PDF files and store the content in the database as text

Comment: The PDFs are the database which are stored in server can be searchable by using Django and Docker